# Looking for references on this adaptive Runge–Kutta method (GSL’s rk2)

Tags: reference-request, runge-kutta

### Background

For a study that is beyond the scope of this question, I applied all of [GSL’s adaptive Runge–Kutta methods](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Stepping-Functions.html) to a certain problem. This includes a Runge–Kutta method of 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> order, denoted as `gsl_odeiv2_step_rk2`. It is arguably a rather bad method, but this makes the method particularly intersting for my application, about which I am writing a paper now. **For this purpose, I am interested in further references about this method, and in particular about its name and origin.**

### The method

The method is mainly what Wikpedia calls [Kutta’s third-order method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Kutta.27s_third-order_method) and uses the [midpoint method or modified Euler method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_method) for error estimation. The Butcher tableau is:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
1 & -1 & 2 \\\hline
& \frac{1}{6} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6} \\
& 0 & 1
\end{array}$$

### My research so far

- In the GSL’s source code, this method is called *Euler–Cauchy,* however all other sources I could find apply this name to the [classical Euler method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), so I am skeptical about this.
- The source code further references [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abramowitz_and_Stegun) for the component methods. The component methods can indeed be found there but is neither equipped with a name nor a reference.
- No other list of Runge–Kutta methods I could find contains the method as a whole. The 2<sup>nd</sup>-order method is usually called *midpoint method.* The only source I could find that mentions the 3<sup>rd</sup>-order method is Wikipedia, which calls it *Kutta’s third-order method,* but lists no source to which I have easy access.

Comment: The second order method is not the implicit midpoint method. It is sometimes called the improved Euler method and sometimes Heun's method.

Comment: @LutzL: I didn’t say that it’s the *implicit* midpoint method; it’s the *explicit* midpoint method. As for the other names, I did find it to be called *improved Euler* but never *Heun’s method.* The latter is used for the method with the following Butcher tableau in all resources I could find so far: $$\begin{array}{c|cc} 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\\hline & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{array}$$

Comment: Yes. I misremembered the wikipedia page on Heun's method, too much emphasis on the section there about the Ralston method.

Answer (score 5):

John Butcher's [Numerical Methods for Ordinary Differential Equations](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470723351.html) lists your 3rd-order method as (233f) on page 95, though it gives no attribution.  The 2nd-order method is of course well-known as you say.  I know of no reference that suggests pairing them, but it is a fairly obvious embedded error estimator for this particular 3rd-order method.

The 3rd-order method is not mentioned in the book of Hairer, Wanner, & Norsett, nor in Butcher's [paper on the history of Runge-Kutta methods](http://people.cs.vt.edu/~asandu/Public/Qual2011/DiffEqn/Butcher_1996_RK-history.pdf).

Comment: Fehlberg (1969) wrote about pairing the 2nd and the 3rd order RK methods: [Low-order classical Runge-Kutta formulas with stepsize control and their application to some heat transfer problems](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19690021375), p. 24.

Answer (score 3):

Only a partial answer:

I managed to take a look into Kutta’s *[Beitrag zur näherungweisen Integration totaler Differentialgleichungen](https://archive.org/details/zeitschriftfrma12runggoog/page/438/mode/2up?view=theater),* which does indeed mention and derive the 3<sup>rd</sup>-order method, giving no other source than relating it to [Simpson’s rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule). Thus I deem it appropriate to call it *Kutta’s third-order method.*

Comment: Nice.  Did you find an electronic copy?

Comment: No, I used my university library’s service of summoning the original journal from the archives to a room in which I could read it (but nothing more).

Comment: Electronic copy: https://archive.org/details/zeitschriftfrma12runggoog/page/438/mode/2up?view=theater for the discussion of the 3rd order methods and on the following page the method under discussion as just another parameter variant.